# Using moment.js with lang file and require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, momentjs

I'm currently trying to use the moment.js library with require.js and I'm still having trouble understanding the correct setup of such a project. Here is what I do in my main.js file:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'app',

        paths: {
            // ... more parameters (all Backbone related)
            'moment': 'lib/moment',
            'moment_de': 'lib/lang/de',
        },

    shim: {
        'moment' : {
            deps: [],
        },

        'moment_de': {
            deps: ['moment'],
        },

        // ... more parameters (all Backbone related)
    }
});
```

I'm using a separate module for configuration purposes. The module looks like this:

```
define(['moment', 'moment_de'], function(moment, de) {

    moment.lang('de');

    var configuration = {}
    // ...    
    return configuration;
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to change the global language of the moment object in this file, but I'm running into the following error messages:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "../moment" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

And later on:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'preparse' of undefined
```

The first error message is the language module which is being loaded although it should be loaded AFTER the moment module (if I'm doing it right). The second one is from the moment module that is trying to switch to the language module which hasn't been loaded.

Could someone please shine some light on this issue. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I fixed the problem using the minified language versions (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/develop/min/lang/de.js)). Apparently the minified versions are using the AMD format, which allow for an easier inclusion in require.js projects).

I still don't quite understand why it is not possible to include the languages using the shim config, though. Maybe someone could try to explain that.

Comment: The non-minified files seem sufficiently different to not work as shims. The use of `require("../moment")...` by the non-minified version doesn't seem to play well with RequireJS. The relative module name doesn't get resolved.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to get marked and upvoted...

Answer (score 4):

### Another solution (2015):

This example aims to demonstrate how to use the `moment.js` translations with the `navigator.language` property, usually the preferred language of the user.

Define `moment.js` and the language files separately in your [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs) config, like this:

```
require.config({
  config: {
    'moment': {
      noGlobal: true
    }
  },
  paths: {
    ...
    'moment': '../vendor/moment/moment',
    'moment_de': '../vendor/moment/locale/de',
    'moment_pl': '../vendor/moment/locale/pl'
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

Create a small module, like `lib/moment.js` and specify your language configuration (you can find a list of RFC 4646 language tags [here](http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes)):

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var moment = require('moment'), locale;

  switch(navigator.language) {
    case 'de':
    case 'de-at':
    case 'de-de':
    case 'de-li':
    case 'de-lu':
    case 'de-ch':
      locale = 'moment_de';
    break;

    case 'pl':
      locale = 'moment_pl';
    break;

    ...
  }

  if (locale) {
    require([locale]);
  }

  return moment;
});
```

Please notice: `moment.js` supports English by default.

---

In your [chaplinjs](/questions/tagged/chaplinjs) view class (or any other [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) class/plain script etc), use it like this:

```
define([
  'chaplin'
  'lib/moment'
], function(Chaplin, moment) {
  'use strict';

  var MyView = Chaplin.View.extend({

    ...

    parse: function() {
      ...
      console.log(moment().format('LLL'));
      ...
    }

    ...

  });

  return MyView;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require({
    paths: {
        'moment': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min',
        'moment_de': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/lang/de.min'
    }
}, ['moment', 'moment_de'], function(moment){
    moment.lang('de');
    alert(moment(1316116057189).fromNow());
});
```

You shouldn't need to shim the modules, as moment.js supports AMD.
http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/xYXUC/

Comment: Note that in this example if moment_de depends on moment then you could have problems. The modules in an array such as that are loaded asynchronously.  So it is likely that moment_de could be loaded before moment and you will have periodic errors about moment not being defined.  I am not sure, but I think that is what the shims were for (or that was the idea of the use of shims in the question example and it didnt work).

Comment: I believe the language files declare moment as a dependency. Therefore, it should always be loaded prior. Shims are for libraries that do not support AMD.